# Protected fields not visible to subclasses

Tags: java, android, subclass, protected

I'm writing a custom view that directly extends `android.view.View`. If I try to access fields `mScrollX` or `mScrollY`, I see an error that the field "cannot be resolved or is not a field." The [source code for android.view.View](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/view/View.java;h=65904972d39662613c67f549a26a0213b77747cc;hb=refs/heads/gingerbread-release) has mScrollX, mScrollY, and similar variables declared `protected`. How is it that my direct subclass cannot access protected fields of its parent class? (Classes like [ScrollView](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/ScrollView.java;h=2ad67baa4d423b227123b019e6da44101018269c;hb=refs/heads/gingerbread-release) apparently can.)

P.S. I realize that I can call `getScrollX()`, but I want to update these fields; calling `setScroll()` has side effects that I don't want.

Comment: Weird, subclasses, even being in other packages, can access protected variables of their superclass. I would guess that you're using the wrong version. Can you show some of your code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's because they are not part of the Android SDK.

Here is the source code for `mScrollX`:

```
/**
 * The offset, in pixels, by which the content of this view is scrolled
 * horizontally.
 * {@hide}
 */
@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty(category = "scrolling")
protected int mScrollX;
```

You will notice the `@hide` annotation. That means this is not part of the Android SDK. The part of the build process that creates the Android SDK will not include this data member in the stub edition of `android.view.View` that is in the `android.jar` file that you are compiling against.

The `@hide` annotation is used for things that for internal purposes needed to be public or protected but are not considered something SDK developers should be using.

Please find other solutions for whatever problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Hmm, interesting!  So to paraphrase the rationale: "We couldn't be bothered to sort out proper encapsulation, so we subverted the language."...

Comment: I had noticed the `{@hide}` tag. I assumed it was why `mScrollX` did not appear in the JavaDocs (like the [proposed `@exclude` tag](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/proposed-tags.html), which supercedes `@hide`). I didn't realize that the SDK was a stub version of the API.

Comment: One thing i cant understand is Protected variable of **View** class is accessed in **ScrollView** class. How is this possible ?
Hierarchy is - ScrollView extends FramLayout extends ViewGroup extends View.
So, protected variable of View class should only accessible in ViewGroup.

Answer (score 5):

It's very straight forward: notice the @hide annotation above these variables.
It's an Android-specific annotation that hides the fields/methods from the public SDK. That's why you can't access them directly.

[Romain Guy mentioned it in](http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/browse_thread/thread/898342a0eedb9dec) this post.

Comment: that is disturbing. what's the point of open source? so people can read the source and understand what's going on. but the source released here is a fake one? not the one used in production? that is also acceptable, *if it is transparent*. I don't care if the JDK source is the *real* one, but any information I gained from read it must be true in the real system.

Comment: You have to understand the meaning of open-source. First of all, you can build your own Android version directly from the source, do any modifications you want to it, and use every method or field whether hidden or not. That's what phone manufacturers do and some of the custom ROM cooks in the community. Developers can benefit from another aspect of Android being open-source, and that is going through the source and understand how things work behind the scenes, for me this is as-important as the documentation itself.

Comment: The fact that some fields or methods are hidden is usually one of the following two: 1. They might change in future release of the SDK, so they want to reduce the chance of app-incompatibility, saving you, the developer a lot of work maintaining your apps, and 2. Using these fields directly like in your case might interfere with proper work of how the API's work internally.

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting the fields with reflection:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// ...

try {
    Field scrollXField = View.class.getDeclaredField("mScrollX");
    scrollXField.setAccessible(true);
    scrollXField.set(this, myNewValue);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // oops, android changed the implementation. sucks to be you.
}
```

Note, however, that you're relying on undocumented and unsupported behavior when you do this, and so you should be prepared for things to break on some devices or in future versions.